# How could I use regex / stringr to dynamically see which R packages are used in a GitHub repo?

Tags: r, github, stringr

Suppose I have several R scripts within a GitHub repository, and I'd like to know which packages I've used (loaded) within all of the scripts. How could I accomplish this dynamically with the stringr package? As an example, I'd like to find package names through `library()` calls as shown below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(xml2)
library(jsonlite)
```

In other words, given a string `library(some_package_one)` and another string `library(some_package_two)`, how could I use stringr (and perhaps rvest or similar scraping package) to determine each unique package that has been loaded from various scripts within a repo?

This would allow me to determine which packages I'd need to install before even cloning a given repository.

Take a [miscellaneous repository](https://github.com/hadley/cran-logs-dplyr) from Hadley Wickham.

- There are several scripts within [this repository](https://github.com/hadley/cran-logs-dplyr) that load packages through `library()` calls.
- There are different packages used in different scripts

How could I extract the package names that have been loaded by searching for all `library()` calls?

Comment: You would need to check for calls to 'require' as well. And there are other ways to load packages too. For example the p_load function from the pacman package.

Comment: The checkpoint package has a function that does this - i.e., scans a directory for all package dependencies (including packages that aren't attached to the search path (i.e., b/c the person used :: and not a call to library or require) but are nevertheless loaded. The function in checkpoint I'm talking about is called projectScanPackages. It isn't exported but you can access it using checkpoint:::projectScanPackages